# manage api calls when using vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, ibm-api-management, mobile-data

I am currently working on an asset manager for network/server infrastructure in vue.js.

I am also using vuetify for the look and feel since the goal is to create a progressive web app. Engineers can use their phone to scan tags on company assets to request details.

Currently all data is loaded into the app using a rest api. I am using vuex for state management in the application.

I would like some insights in to when to launch these api requests.

So there is some data i currently load at the start of the web app just after logging in when the main core view is loaded. This is impacting performance. Some examples of loaded data:
-> asset types,vendors,suppliers,...
This data is used in a lot of places in the application. (forms,filters,...)
I prefer not to call the vuex actions to perform the api request form inside a specific component since this could lead to unnecessary request when browsing the app.
The only exception to this being the assets them self since this is a lot of data to load at the start.

The problem i am facing is that on mobile platforms loading the data each time at the start of the app is a waste of data connection. It is possible that the engineer is using the app without actually needing the data.

I know this is kind of an abstract question, i am not looking for the one final awnser. Just some insight or recommendations from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I misunderstood but it sounds like you are prefetching a lot of non critical information all at start up. You should really focus on when that data is actually needed and reach out and retrieve it only when its actually needed. A common case of this is on route change, so if you have multiple pages within your app an admin page is likely going to need data that your home screen doesn't need. Wait until you navigate to that page before you retrieve information specific to that page. This is commonly done within the `beforeRouteEnter` router hook or `created` life cycle hook. Now to build on this, it may take some time to download that new data after a route change - the page could render before all of its necessary data has been made available. You can use a library like [Vue-Promised](https://github.com/posva/vue-promised) to handle that intermediate state for sections that require data that is still loading. This allows you to let the page render quickly without having to wait on all of its data.

A couple other tips to further optimize things:

- If you data that doesn't change often, sometimes it doesn't hurt to persist that data within the browser, either using the [Cache-Control http header](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http-cache-headers#1-cache-control) when making your http calls or by using something like the browsers [LocalStorage](https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-using-localstorage-in-javascript-apps-ba44edb53a36) or one of the hard persistence methods available within the browser. Theres a number of Vuex plugins that make this really easy, ex. [vuex-persist](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist). On startup you can load this data from storage which is faster than making a network call, your app will be able to respond faster and you can even go and make that network request in the background to refresh that data after the page has rendered.
- If retrieving large sets of data is an issue then you can page the data to retrieve it in smaller chunks and only retrieve additional "pages" fo data when the user needs it. In tables this is commonly done using pagination buttons or [infinite scrolling](https://alligator.io/vuejs/implementing-infinite-scroll/). Theres a number of libraries that do both of these as well, pagination would likely be built into the vuetify libraries table component.

Comment: Big time thank you for the response some stuff like pagina for the api is already implemented but there is aan lot of stuff that is really helpful!!